# Proxy problems - New to TOR

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, torsocks, settings

I'm new to TOR and mistakingly fiddled with the proxy settings, now I am unable to establish a connection to TOR. This is the message shown:

9/12/18, 16:09:54.536 [WARN] You specified a public address '203.168.53.32:37527' for SocksPort. Other people on the Internet might find your computer and use it as an open proxy. Please don't allow this unless you have a good reason. 
9/12/18, 16:09:54.537 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tor Browser Bundle, you can simply re-download to a new location (or write over the existing location) and all settings will return to default.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem in error message is that you have specified the **globally accessible address** for something that is supposed to be private. Just revise your config! Post it here and I'll be able to provide you with a precise instructions how to do it